# Google Analytics click events tracking in chrome Extension Content script (Shadow DOM)

Tags: events, google-chrome-extension, google-analytics, content-script, message-passing

I am building a Chrome Extension with a user interface injected into the pages DOM via a content script.

I have injected the code into a Shadow Root to prevent CSS bleed - and everything is actually starting to come out really nice :-)

BUT I am struggling a bit with Google analytics. I would like to track a mix of different click-events on buttons in the content script (+ on the settings page) to get a better feel of how users are navigating the extension (+ of course page visits).

I struggle with the documentation of message passing to the background script from Google and haven't been able to find some real life examples.

I am unsure how this will work - and what I should actually pass through to the background script in the first place? . Will the content script send a message to background on every click, or will there only be passed an object with info on the event to track from the background script?

I am a bit lost here: My understanding of message-passing between content-script and background like this is rather limited...

I got 2 "work in progress" code snippets so far to work with...

**Background Script code so far:**

```
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX']);
_gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/u/ga_debug.js';     // ----> 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js'
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();

// here I receive the message from the content script page
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {

      //track event - create
      if(request.action == "analytics_add_item"){
          _gaq.push(['_trackEvent',
              request.action,
              request.item_name.toLowerCase(),
              request.item_stat,
              request.item_number
          ]);
      }
```

});

**content script:**

```
function trackButtonClick(e) {
 console.log('action: "analytics_add_item"', e.target.name);
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({analytics_add_item: e.target.name});
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', e.target.id, 'clicked']);
}

// let lotsUnitsSlider already defined elsewhere in code (this is a toggle-button)
lotsUnitsSlider.name = lotsUnitsSlider;
lotsUnitsSlider.addEventListener('click', trackButtonClick);
```

Can anyone help me a bit on my way - thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Your content script is sending an object with `analytics_add_item` property but the listener checks `action` property and wants a bunch of other properties, which you don't send.

Add the missing properties to the message object:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
  action: 'analytics_add_item',
  item_name: e.target.name,
  item_stat: 'foo',
  item_number: 'bar',
});
```

P.S. You can use devtools debugger to actually see what happens, what's being sent and received by setting a breakpoint in the listener (the background script devtools is [opened through chrome://extensions page](/a/10258029)).

Comment: Thanks for your response wOxxOm!

I think I am a bit lost here - I am missing some basic understanding of both Google Analytics and message passing in general.

If I look at general info about event tracking with analytics code I get something like this:

Category (Required) 
Action (Required) .
Label (Optional)
Value (Optional) 


So - I have a clickevent on a button. So: category: contentscript - action: click, label: lotsUnitsSlider ?

Comment: I am really lost here! Google descripes event tracking like:

onclick=ga(‘send’, ‘event’, [eventCategory], [eventAction], [eventLabel], [eventValue]);

Category (Required), Action (Required), Label (Optional),Value (Optional).

But what would I send to the background then?

Comment: I answered the part about messaging and I believe my answer is clear enough already. I don't know anything about analytics so I can't answer that. You may want to ask a separate question.

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm - I appreciate your time and help!